# fullcalendar V4 dayClick not firing

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to convert an old Fullcalendar based web app to V4.  I can not get `dayClick` to fire.

I have this CodePen example: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMMEyN?&editable=true&editors=001](http://Hi,%20%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20convert%20an%20old%20Fullcalendar%20based%20web%20app%20to%20V4.%20%20I%20can%20not%20get%20%60dayClick%60%20to%20fire.%20%20I%20have%20this%20CodePen%20example:%20https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMMEyN?&editable=true&editors=001)

The example was initialized via a lik=nk from the FC web site.  See below.  It brings up a `dayGridMonth` view by default.  It includes the `interaction` plugin but the `dayClick` method does not fire, no matter what day cell i click in.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        defaultDate: '2019-04-07',
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        dayClick: function(info) {
                    alert("dayClick ");
        },
        events: [
          {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-04-01'
          },
          {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-04-07',
            end: '2019-04-10'
          },
          {
            groupId: '999',
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-04-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            groupId: '999',
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-04-16T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2019-04-11',
            end: '2019-04-13'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2019-04-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2019-04-12T12:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2019-04-12T12:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2019-04-12T14:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2019-04-13T07:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2019-04-28'
          }
        ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
```

Comment: In v4 and v5, **dayClick** (fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayClick) has effectively been replaced with **dateClick** (fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you meant `dateClick` instead of `dayClick`:

```
dateClick: function(info) {
    alert("dateClick");
},
```

for reference: [dateClick() docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick)

Comment: Hi, thank you.  you are correct that I had the wrong js there.  It should have just been `alert(...)`.  I have editied my question.

Comment: Hi, no problem. Let me know if `dateClick` works for you, otherwise I can try to help you out further.

Comment: Hi, even with my modification or changing it to `console.log()` `dayClick` is not firing.

Comment: Please read my answer again, the issue is in the fact that you named your function `dayClick()` instead of the correct `dateClick()`, the `console.log` is irrelevant.

Comment: @7 Reeds that's because there is no such thing as dayClick in v4 anymore. It's dateClick. Read the answer more carefully. Also you could try checking the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting

Comment: yup, I totally spaced the name change in this version.  Sorry.  Cheers